# Clipping raster data from a .gpkg file with multi polygon extents

Tags: qgis, raster, geopackage

Can you clip raster data to polygon extents created in a .gpkg file in QGIS? I've mapped tree canopies and would like to get raster derived values such as max height of trees using DSM data, and other raster derived values as well. I've just noticed the Toolbox icon isn't being presented as an option in the Attributes Toolbar.

Comment: Have you tried the [zonal statistics tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalstatisticsfb)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*the Toolbox icon isn't being presented as an option in the Attributes Toolbar.*" but you can open the toolbox from the processing menu - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU3Zh.png